# Zsh git branch missing from right side of my screen

Tags: git, zsh

I'm using zsh on iTerm2 but I noticed that I don't have the git branch titled master on the right side of my screen like I've seen on examples in blogs. How do I get it?

My zsh:
[image]

Other people's zsh (notice the "master" on the right side of the screen):
[image]

Comment: They use a customized prompt. The right hand side is controlled by `$RPROMP`(or `$RPS1`which is the same). There are a lot of prompt suggestions out there, just google for _git zsh prompt_

Comment: That should read `$RPROMPT` above, sorry for the typo.